Node-oracledb, Date column in select result on nodejs app, appears 1 day less than date column in Oracle database
Node-oracledb, Date column in select result on app.js side, appears 2 days less than date columns in Oracle database.
select appointment_date from appointments where id = 1;
result on Oracle:
2024-08-07T10:10:08.000Z
on Node.js app I get this output:
2024-08-06T10:10:08.000Z
I added these lines at the top of the code document, but it doesn't work:
process.env.TZ = 'UTC';  process.env.ORA_SDTZ = 'UTC';
process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; 
process.env.ORA_SDTZ = 'UTC'; 

const oracledb = require('oracledb');

oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig)
.then(async function (connection) {
   
  return connection.execute(
    'select appointment_date from appointments where id = 1',    
    [], // no binds
    {
      outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
    }
  )
    .then(function (result) {
      console.log(result.rows);
      connection.close();      
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      connection.close();      
    });
})
.catch(function (error) {   
});

References I tried to solve the problem:
node-oracledb Documentation for the Oracle Database Node.js Add-on
Fetching Dates and Timestamps - https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html
